# How to fit data into a machine leaning model in parts?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am working on a text classification problem. I have huge amount of data and when I am trying to fit data into the machine learning model it is causing a memory error. Is there any way through which I can fit data in parts to avoid memory error.

**Additional information**

1. I am using linearSVC model.
2. I have training data of 1.1 million rows.
3. I have vectorized text data using tfidf.
4. The shape of vectorized data (1121063, 4235687) which has to be
   fitted into the model.

Or is there any other way out of this problem.
Unfortunately, I don't have any reproducible code for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably ask this question in https://ai.stackexchange.com/ . It would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is not to use what I assume is the scikit-learn implementation of `linearSVC` and instead use some algorithm/implementation that allows training in batches. Most common of which are neural networks, but several other algorithms exists. In `scikit-learn` look for classifiers with the `partial_fit` method which will allow you to fit your classifier in batches. See e.g. [this list](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning)

Comment: Probably not the answer the OP wanted to get, but certainly the correct one !

Answer (score 0):

You could also try what's suggested from sklearn.svm import SVC (the second part, the first is using LinearSVC, which you did):

> For large datasets consider using :class:'sklearn.svm.LinearSVC' or
>   **:class:'sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier' instead, possibily after a :class:'sklearn.kernel_approximation.Nystroem' transformer**.

If you check SGDClassifier() you can set the parameter "warm_start=True" so when you iterate trough your dataset it won't lose it's state.:

```
clf = SGDClassifier(warm_start=True)
for i in 'loop your data':
    clf.fit(data[i])
```

Additionally you could **reduce the dimension of your dataset** by removing some words **from your TFIDF** model. **Check the "max_df" and "min_df" parameters**, they'll remove words with frequency higher than or lower than, can be a % or an unit.